# Migrate Joomla 3 Site to new domain

Tags: mysql, migration, joomla3.0

I have built a Joomla site for a client on a development server.  It soon needs migrating to the client's Live site, which will mean a URL change as well as a physical server change.

I'm new to Joomla, but having worked a lot on WordPress previously I know it's a piece of cake to migrate one WP site to another, especially with the dozen or so available plugins.

However, this doesn't appear to be so easy on Joomla.  I have searched for the best practice to achieve this with Joomla 3 but cannot find what I need.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are in fact a two ways to achieve this and they are quite easy.**

**1.** The first one is the manual way, that is:

- Copy the files of your local joomla installation and upload them to
  your server
- Export your local database and import it on your server.
- Edit the configuration.php file to your new server credentials -db
  name, db user, db server etc.

**2.** The second one is through the [akeeba](https://www.akeebabackup.com/) backup component.

- In this case you create a backup and then restore it on the remote
  server. Detailed info
  [here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/a-typical-backup-restoration-workflow.html).

> After uploading your remote site you are advised to follow [these
>   guidelines](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-to-secure-a-new-joomla-installation)
>   to secure your installation.

Comment: This is an excellent response.  I went with Option 2 and it worked perfectly when I followed the instructions carefully.  Thanks very much.